# Sequelize not returning asked model even when using `include: [{ model: this.buildModel, required: true }]`

Tags: typescript, model, sequelize.js, repository, sequelize-typescript

I am out of clues to solve this issue. Even though I believe to have made a correct migration, model definition and query, I can't get the `build` in my `iteration`.

Here is the models :

`SequelizeBuildModel.ts`

```
@Table({
  tableName: 'playablebuild',
  underscored: true,
})
export class SequelizeBuildModel extends Model<
  BuildModelAttributes,
  BuildModelCreationAttributes
> {
  public id!: number;

  ...

  @HasMany(() => SequelizeIterationModel)
  public iterations!: SequelizeIterationModel[];

  ...
}
```

`SequelizeIterationModel.ts`

```
import {
  BelongsTo,
  Column,
  ForeignKey,
  Model,
  Table,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { SequelizeBuildModel } from './SequelizeBuildModel';
import { DataTypes, Optional } from 'sequelize';

export interface IterationModelAttributes {
  id: number;
  buildId: number;
  config: Record<string, unknown>;
}

export type IterationModelCreationAttributes = Optional<
  IterationModelAttributes,
  'id'
>;

@Table({
  tableName: 'iteration',
  underscored: true,
})
export class SequelizeIterationModel extends Model<
  IterationModelAttributes,
  IterationModelCreationAttributes
> {
  @BelongsTo(() => SequelizeBuildModel, { foreignKey: 'build_id' })
  public build!: SequelizeBuildModel;

  @ForeignKey(() => SequelizeBuildModel)
  @Column
  public buildId!: number;

  @Column({ type: DataTypes.JSONB })
  public config!: Record<string, unknown>;
}
```

Here is the query :

`SequelizeIterationRepository`

```
import { Iteration } from '../../../domain/entities/Iteration';
import { IterationRepository } from '../../../domain/ports/IterationRepository';
import {
  IterationModelCreationAttributes,
  SequelizeIterationModel,
} from '../models/SequelizeIterationModel';
import { InjectModel } from '@infra';
import { IterationMapper } from '../mappers/IterationMapper';
import { SequelizeBuildModel } from '../models/SequelizeBuildModel';

export class SequelizeIterationRepository implements IterationRepository {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('SequelizeIterationModel')
    private readonly iterationModel: typeof SequelizeIterationModel,
    @InjectModel('SequelizeBuildModel')
    private readonly buildModel: typeof SequelizeBuildModel,
  ) {}

  public async save(iteration: Iteration): Promise<Iteration> {
    const parsedIteration = IterationMapper.toPersistence(iteration);
    return this.create(parsedIteration);
  }

  private async create(
    iteration: IterationModelCreationAttributes,
  ): Promise<Iteration> {
    const rawIteration = await this.iterationModel.create(iteration, {
      include: [{ model: this.buildModel, required: true }],
    });
    return IterationMapper.toDomain(rawIteration);
  }
}
```

I am specifically focusing on those line, where `rawIteration` stays empty no matter what :

```
      include: [{ model: this.buildModel, required: true }],
    });
```

When I am looking inside the DB, the relationship and foreign are corrects as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/creating-with-associations/) it appears that you want to use a key of 'association' instead of 'model'. The `required: true` is also likely to be unnecessary.